# Code won't display all stripped, extracted text on website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

very new to Python. The following code will only allow me to display individual p entries from the extracted website (the first entry, 0, being the current example).

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Thug"

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
page_soup.findAll("p")

paragraphs = page_soup.findAll("p")
paragraph = paragraphs[0].text.strip()

print(paragraph)
```

For some reason, I can't grip the particular **for** argument I would need to display all of the p elements on the site in a single block of text.

The eventual goal of the above code snippet is a reading grade level app, hence the stripped down text. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to take all the paragraphs and join them together to make one string?

Comment: Exactly, so I can eventually parse the text to display a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not near my laptop to include the output, but generally it would be:

```
paragraphs = page_soup.findAll("p")
for para in paragraphs:
    print (para.text.strip())
```

Comment: Perfect. I think the ten iterations I tried all danced around the fact that 1. I kept using an already defined variable after the "for" above and 2. I placed the text.strip() function outside of the print function. As an idiot would. Thank you!

Comment: Nope, not an idiot! You’re just learning. Try things out, ask for help, keep practicing and try new things. We all are at different levels, but all had to start at the beginning at some point.

Comment: Much appreciated, I'll definitely take your advice to heart. Thank you!